# I've many parent elements with class news how can i select children on one from other children in same parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to set display of class .change from class .cha in the current class .news

```
 $(function () {

        $('.cha').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().find('.change').css('display','inline');
            });
});
```

Comment: Post your `html` too..

Comment: $(' [currentNews] .cha .change').css('something', 'something'); ?

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.button').click(function(){
    $('ul li:nth-child(3)').addClass('red');
  });
});
```

```css
.red{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
 <head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <ul>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
  <li>item4</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="button">Select</a>

  <!-- jQuery -->


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hope your Answer is got

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What is the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: you did't write "jQuery(document).ready(function($){", so you need to write this if you want to use jQuery library.

Comment: The OP's code includes `$(function(){ ... })`, which is "shorthand for `$(document).ready()`." See [Using jQuery Core](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/#post-123).